# Bootstrap 3 non-responsive issue?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

Still can't handle with issue in non-responsive bootstrap3 http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

If you'll resize window to less then .container width you'll see 1px width space in this example too. I also got it on my iOS devices. And this kills me!

Screenshot http://cl.ly/image/1f0w342Q1q0a

Comment: That is not happening to me. Could you update your post with steps to reproduce it? Add also your browser version.

Comment: OSX Chrome version 41.0.2258.2 canary (64-bit)

Comment: OSX Version 41.0.2251.0 dev (64-bit) and Version 41.0.2258.2 canary (64-bit) don't show it on my Macbook Air (see http://imgur.com/oMzy8TS). Do you perhaps have a retina screen?